# Change the default browser in yakuake

Tags: browser, yakuake

I use yakuake as drop-down-terminal in Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I click on a link on the console to open it in browser, it opens in the default kde-browser `webbrowser-app`.

I tried to uninstall webbrowser-app, but that would uninstall those packages too:

```
libunity-webapps0 unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service webapp-container
```

I am not sure, if I still need them.

#### How do I change the default browser in yakuake?

Comment: Did you try to open the "details" settings? What browser is set as default there?

Comment: @xangua where is that exactly? There's no "details" in the profile settings, nor Yakuake settings...

Comment: I am also curious about this. I tried all of the various ways to set the default browser, but I ended up just uninstalling Firefox so Yakuake would use Chrome instead.